# Print a variable selected by a random number

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, random, introspection

I have a list of names, and I would like my program to randomly select one of those names. I tried using the following:

```
import random


def main():

    Arkansas = 1
    Manchuria = 2
    Bengal = "3"
    Baja_California = 4
    Tibet = 5
    Indonesia = 6
    Cascade_Range = 7
    Hudson_Bay = 8
    High_Plains = 9
    map = random.randrange(1, 10)
    print(map)

main()
```

I also tried making each of the numbers as strings, using the `eval()`function for `randrange()`, but none of this worked.

Comment: Why not `random.choice(('Arkansas', 'Manchuria', ...))` or have a map `{1: 'Arkansas', ...}` or ...

Comment: Guys, why are you downvoting? I mean it's a brand new OP and may seem like a simple question to you, but it has code, it passes "What have you tried?" What do you people want? Just posters that already know the answers to their own question?

Comment: The "I also tried..." sentence is not useful. We don't know what he actually tried, or what the (undesired) result of that attempt was, how `eval` was used, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't assign numbers OR strings. Use a list.

```
choices = ['Arkansas', 'Manchuria', 'Bengal', 'Baja California']   # etc.
```

Then take a `random.choice`

```
random_choice = random.choice(choices)
```

Comment: If you're truly concerned with helping a new coder, I'd suggest more explanation as to _why_ this is the right thing to do, and definitely better variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {1:"Arkansas", 2:"Manchuria", 3:"Bengal",
           4:"Baja California", 5:"Tibet", 6:"Indonesia", 
           7:"Cascade Range", 8:"Hudson Bay", 9:"High Plain"}
map = random.randrange(1, 10)
print(my_dict[map])
```

Using a list and `random.choice()` is probably the better option (easier to read, less bytes), but if you have to assign numbers, this will work.

Comment: Not a bad solution if you know the bounds of the keys in advance. Could get hairy if the keys weren't exactly a contiguous sequence of integers, or not integers at all. If the dict is constructed exactly for this purpose, this is fine.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I just edited in that the list with `random.choice()` is the better option, but this does work

Comment: It would be more robust to use ``random.choice()`` on ``my_dict``'s keys. ``print(my_dict[random.choice(my_dict.keys())])``

Answer (score 0):

I do this by assigning a random floating point number to a string item in a list and sort the list alphabetically. Each time you will get a different output. I do the same in Excel and OpenOffice Calc actually. Simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random

L=['Arkansas', 'Manchuria', 'Bengal', 'Baja California', 'Tibet', 'Indonesia', 'Cascade_Range', 'Hudson Bay', 'High_Plains']

tmp=[]

for item in L:
    item=str(random.random())+'|'+item
    tmp.append(item)

tmp.sort()

for item in tmp:
    print item[item.find('|')+1:]
```

Output 1

```
Bengal
Manchuria
Tibet
Indonesia
High_Plains
Arkansas
Baja California
Cascade_Range
Hudson Bay
```

Output 2

```
Bengal
Baja California
Manchuria
Tibet
Arkansas
High_Plains
Cascade_Range
Hudson Bay
Indonesia
```

if you want to get just one name you can break the loop:

```
for item in tmp:
    print item[item.find('|')+1:]
    break
```

Output 1

```
Baja California
```

Output 2

```
Cascade_Range
```

Comment: Much more complicated than all of the other solutions, but very creative.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `tmp = L[:]; random.shuffle(tmp)` here - much more explicit and much more efficient...